# Where Is Coupon Code Field in CartThrob?

Tags: expressionengine, cartthrob

There is a coupon_code variable listed on this page of the CartThrob docs:
http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/coupon_info/index.html#coupon_code

Where exactly is the data for this variable coming from? There isn't a "coupon_code" field on the default Coupon channel that get's set up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the CT settings under discount, you can define the channel and the custom fields within that channel to be used. ie. coupon code = title & coupon settings = CT discount FT

Comment: Perfect! I set up a new custom field and assigned it to the coupon_code variable. This way I can have a Title and a Code. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The coupon code comes from the title.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it comes from the url_title field when you publish a coupon code.